# Does the Bible give the reasons (if any) for God choosing Abraham?

Tags: abraham, predestination

Is there any reason given in the Bible as to why God chose Abram to be the father of Israel?

For example, Noah seems to be chosen by God because he is Righteous.

> "Noah was a righteous man, blameless in his generation." (Gen 6:9 ESV)

**Is any reason given for God choosing Abram/Abraham to be the father of Israel?**

Comment: Based on Hebrews 11:6 and Hebrews 11 in general, I think part of the reason was because Abraham was a man of great faith, but there's no clear answer. Since extra-biblical sources are in scope with your question, you might also be interested in the Book of Abraham, which is considered scripture to members of The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints, and talks more about Abraham's calling (https://www.lds.org/scriptures/pgp/abr?lang=eng).

Comment: @SamuelBradshaw Please consider making that an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Scripture gives this answer:

> **Genesis 18:18-19 King James Version (KJV)**
>
> 18 Seeing that Abraham shall surely become a great and mighty nation,
>   and all the nations of the earth shall be blessed in him?
>
> 19 For I know him, that he will command his children and his household
>   after him, and they shall keep the way of the Lord, to do justice and
>   judgment; that the Lord may bring upon Abraham that which he hath
>   spoken of him.

God, in His perfect Omniscience chose Abraham because He knew Abraham would fulfill His purpose.

More [here](http://www.classicalliberalarts.com/page.cfm/page/279/Why-Abraham).

Comment: Brother, where's the "Like" button on his article!

Answer (score 0):

No reason given in the Bible.

The context of Genesis 18:18-19 is whether God should tell Abraham that He is going to destroy Sodom.

Note: "Noah was a righteous man, blameless in his generation." (Gen 6:9 ESV) is because he was regenerated by God (God's grace through faith in Jesus - the one and only way according to John 14:6).  In addition, there is no conjunction "because" in Gen 6:9, rather this verse is the third of the nine toledots (generations) in Genesis.